# AuthO test with postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, auth0

I've registered with 
https://auth0.com/
created a client for my test app

So I want to test sending a Get request to my restful api using Postman as the client.

I have obtain the access token

the documentation on Auth0 just says

to send the request with header

headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ' } }

but how do i do this in Postman?

It Postman they allow configuration of Authorization
when I choose OAuth 1.0
I get a list of required input properties like

Consumer Key
Consumer Secret
Token
Token Secret 
etc..

Comment: The postman tab you’re seeing is for if you haven’t obtained an access token yet, it can help you obtain one. The header can be set in the headers section of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the authorization token with you, you can just add the header `Authorization` with the value `Bearer <your_token>` in the postman request.

Alternatively, you can import their postman collection which imports all of their APIs into your Postman installation. Refer to [this link](https://auth0.com/docs/api/postman).

Answer (score 2):

Simply add header with authorization as key and bearer as its value

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should hopefully be able to just add a Header to the Postman request with a Key of 'Authorization' and a value of 'Bearer '

You likely need to complete the authorization flow (using key and secret etc.) before you get a token you can use though.

Hope it helps!